# can't get a solution to a vectors question

Tags: vector-spaces

We have :
$|\vec{u}|=1 ,|\vec{v}|=5 ,\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=3$

$\vec{w}=(\vec{u}-\vec{v})\times(2\vec{u}+\vec{v})$

we have to calculate $|\vec{w}|$

after playing with equations we have in our solution : $15cos(\alpha)=1$

while $\alpha$ is the angle between u and v

how can we get the answer ? it should be 12 and I think we are doing something wrong

Comment: What is $X$ ? What is the operation $\vec{u} \vec{v}$ (inner product, something else) ?

Comment: its a cross product operation between two vectors
and uv is a scalar multiplication

Comment: sorry for bad latex formatting

Comment: $\vec u\vec v$ is a scalar multiplication ? You meant $|\vec u||\vec v|=3$ ?

Comment: I meant : $\vec{v}\vec{u}=|\vec{v}||\vec{u}|cos(\alpha)=3$

while $\alpha$ is the angle between the vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$

Comment: Ok, that's the inner product then: $\langle\vec u,\vec v\rangle$.

Comment: edited the uv thing now clear ? it is actually a dot product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note $\vec{u}\times \vec{v}=-\vec{v}\times \vec{u}, \vec{u}\times \vec{u}=0$, hence

$\vec{w}=(\vec{u}-\vec{v})\times(2\vec{u}+\vec{v})=3\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ by linearity of cross product.

$|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}|^2=|\vec{u}|^2|\vec{v}|^2-|\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}|^2=16$

$|\vec{w}|=12$

Comment: can you tell me what you relied on in this step in the third line ?

Comment: @WasFr This is called Lagrange identity. $a\times b=|a||b|\sin(\theta), a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos(\theta)$

Comment: I know these identities but I'm not able to determine how you used them in the third line can you explain how you got there ?

Comment: @WasFr You mean why Lagrange identity holds?$|a×b|^2=(|a||b|sin(\theta))^2=(|a||b|)^2(1-cos^2(\theta))=(|a||b|)^2-(|a||b|cos(\theta))^2=(|a||b|)^2-(a\cdot b)^2$

Comment: thank you ! now it is clear